# Bindings namespacing in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I created a Knockout component for which I created some custom bindings. One of them is a binding called `textInput`.

Now I want to upgrade to Knockout 3.2, but found that they created a new `textInput` binding too which will collide with my binding.

I want to upgrade to the new version and don't want to rename my binding because it's referenced in plenty of places. I need something like "namespacing" for bindings. Something that I can use to organize my bindings to not collide with other native or custom bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to 'namespace' your binding handlers, just create them using a 'dotted' name, e.g. "my.namespace.textInput". That way you would also use them by including the 'namespace'.

An example of this would be:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['my.namespace.textInput'] = {
    //Same content as you already have in your binding handler.
};
```

Usage of this binding handler could then look like:

```
<input data-bind="my.namespace.textInput: myValueProperty" />
```

I've put an example of using this naming approach on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4zwo8s30/.

Comment: I thought I tried this before and didn't work. I thought then that it's because KO parses bindings as a JS object literal and dots are not valid in property names. I'll test it again and come back.

Comment: I changed all my bindings as per your solution and they work well. The only downside is that Visual Studio doesn't recognize this syntax and considers it an error. Thank you for your answer

Comment: It didn't work when I previously tried it because I wrote the bindings this way `ko.bindingHandlers.my={ namespaced: { bindingHandler: { update: … } } };`

Comment: You could also just do prefixes instead of 'namespaces'. Prefix all your own custom bindings with 'c_', 'my_', a company/product name or similar. That way it should work fine in VS as well. Regarding the dot in property names it is a javascript feature that you can refer to properties either by using a dot or by using an indexer. In the second case you can use some characters in your property names which you could not otherwise use. But just going with a prefix instead of trying to namespace things might be a better idea.